# Why i am not able to execute this code in automation?

Tags: python, selenium

I could not able to access this code it is showing Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class execute(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            chrome_options: Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            chrome_options.add_argument("--Person1")
            chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
            driver.get('http://localhost/dashboard/user/login')


        def login(self):
         self.driver.find_element_by_id('uemail').send_keys('xyz@gmail.com')
         self.driver.find_element_by_id('upwd').send_keys('123')
         self.driver.find_element_by_id('upwd').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        def test_method(self):
            self.setUp()
            self.login()

        def TearDown(self):
            self.driver.close()

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            unittest.main()
```

Comment: Are your last 2 lines really indented into the class? You need to pull them out of the class, so the `if ...` starts at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Indeed, looking at selenium example.. your ident is off. Either by faulty copy/paste or by actual error. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-to-write-tests

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

you have this indented incorrectly.. therefore `unittest.main()` will not execute.

`chrome_options: Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`

this is not valid Python.  You probably mean:

`chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`